# How can I insert data from one server to another through query

Tags: postgresql

I need to insert records from one database table to another database table. These two databases are in 2 different server.
I could show database A table A records in a dataset.

```
    Sda. Fill(dataset1)
```

How can i insert the values in the dataset 1 to table
Tried as below

```
Pgcommand.CommandText="insert into tablB(id, name)Select (id, name) from dataset1;"
```

How can I insert data from dataset to a table. Or any other way. Reason for using the query is -> I need to schedule this query(in Visual studio) using task scheduler so that it will run every 1 hour.
Thanks

Comment: Create a foreign table and you can use a simple INSERT… SELECT… statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `dblink` is available to you then something like this could be used:

```
INSERT INTO db1.public.table1 (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM dblink('host=hostname user=username password=password dbname=db2',
            'SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table1')
AS data(column1 datatype1, column2 datatype2, column3 datatype3);
```

Comment: Npgsql.PostgresException: '0A000: cross-database references are not implemented: "test.public.tab" -> Error as above.

Comment: You have to have dblink enabled, that's why I said "if dblink is available"  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-function.html